# Data Merge adobe indesign scripting from unique identifier

Tags: sql, scripting, adobe, uniqueidentifier, adobe-indesign

Currently I have a document with a rough layout for a catalog that I have developed. However, I would like to try and make it as quick as possible.

I have master pages for each section, and each page is different as you can tell from the image below.

[image: example]

The info id like to pull is an image from a folder, the price, the written section and the bullet points. the codes are highlighted as you can tell.

I was wondering: is there a way, preferably through Adobe scripting and data merge, to get data on each page from either a server or csv document where the user has input a variable(in the red box). It would be kind of like one would do on a html page where you enter a code/unique identifier in a textbox. then the rest of that section populates the data in that textbox.

Is there a way to do it without a 3rd party application that will cost an arm and a leg. If so are there any links that could help explain how this is done.

Comment: I suggest you start thinking "XML"... https://helpx.adobe.com/indesign/using/importing-xml.html FYI Indata plugin is  probably the most powerful 3rd party plugin, but is quite costy

Comment: Thanks for trying. I was looking at 3rd party plugins and figured I need xml my question was. Can it be done without 3rd party plugins or ones that cost a lot. If I were to use these plugin I was looking at easy catalogue. But id prefer not to use 1

Comment: Be careful with hidden costs. You could possibly get the work done thanks to XML and Scripting. However if you have few to none experience with those two topics, the learning curve will be huge. You will spend a lot of time getting something to work as expected. Indeed EasyCatalog is pricy but it will save you so many efforts that you will want to buy it twice:D Once that said, there are other solutions such as InCatalog that may be less expensive.